# Why is the editor toolbar grayed out for unregistered users?

Tags: feature-request, design, unregistered-users

Why is the editor toolbar grayed out for unregistered users on sites where they can post answers?

I don't think it really makes sense for it to be grayed out if they *can post answers* - what's the point of it being grayed out *just to ungray them again* when the user clicks in the textarea?

Can we make it so it is permanently *ungrayed* out please?

Before click:
[image]

After click:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is way to make unregistered users "unwelcomed" to answer, so they might have a bigger chance to register... Maybe..

Comment: But does SE really *want* (so much that it makes them feel unwelcomed) users to sign up? I don't think so...

Comment: hence "perhaps" and "maybe"...